# Postgres partitioning use case for business to be implemented

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning

Please find my use case below and suggest the appropriate solution:

We have done declarative partitioning over our table A based on some key and further range sub partitioned each partition on the basis of createddate range of 90 days.

In the search query to display last 90 day data , I give both column B and  createddate which may pick any of the required partitions.

But how can I display last 90 days data in which a record which is modified last is also shown at the top but its created date might not lie in the last 90 days range..

Basically, I need to partition my huge table based on some key and also on date to split the data into smaller dataset for faster query . The UI needs to display the latest modified records first but the created date also needs to be given in the query to pick the right partition...

Can we do partition differently to achieve this?
Should i find the max modified date  and give it in the range of the created date.

Yes I have a btree index on the modified_date column currently.

SELECT  *  FROM partitioned_table  where
A ='Value'
AND created_date >= '2021-03-01 08:16:13.589' and created_date <= '2021-04-02 08:16:13.589'  ORDER BY viewpriority desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY;

Here viewpriority is basically a long value containing created_date in milliseconds.

**Issue here is** : **I want to  somehow include modified_date also in this query to get the records sorted by modified_date . But that sorting will happen only in the specified created_date range only.  I want those latest modified records also whose created_date might not lie in this range.**

Comment: Your description is pretty unclear. Perhaps some sample data would help.

Comment: So what is the problem?  Write the query you want and run it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. If it is fast then it is fast.  If it is slow then at least we will have some data about it, rather than blind speculation.  Best if you can turn on track_io_timing first.